# Flutter: How to let several buttons in a line automatic match screen width?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

There have several same size buttons in a line, each button have 8px gap. when device screen width is larger, the width of buttons are wider. when device screen width is smaller, the width of buttons are shorter. but 8px gap are not change.

Here is my code with fixed width: I add a sizedbox widget to give button size.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'modules/globals.dart';

class SourceButtons extends StatefulWidget {
  SourceButtons({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _SourceButtonsStatus();
  }
}

class _SourceButtonsStatus extends State<SourceButtons> {
  var currentSourceIndex = 0;

   List<Widget> getButtons() {
     List<Widget> list = [];
    sourceNames.asMap().forEach((index, source) {
      list.add(SourceButton(onPressCallback: ()=>{
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg:"press down")
      }, title: source));
      list.add(SizedBox(width: 8));
    });
    return list;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:8.0, horizontal: 8.0),

      child: 
      Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Input", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: this.getButtons())],
      )

      ,);

  }
}


class SourceButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onPressCallback;
  final String title;
  bool isActive;
  SourceButton({this.onPressCallback, this.title, this.isActive = false});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 60, // fixed width!!
      height: 35,
      child: RaisedButton(
      color: this.isActive ? Theme.of(context).highlightColor:Theme.of(context).accentColor,
      onPressed: onPressCallback,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(18.0)),
      child: FittedBox(
          fit:BoxFit.fitWidth,
          child:Text(
            this.title,
            style: this.isActive ? Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body2
      )),
    ));
  }
}
```

Ok, base on Udit Chugh's suggest, I add follow function to count out width of button:

```
    double getWidth(BuildContext context, double percentage, int amount, double gap){

  double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  return (width*percentage)/amount - gap;
}
```

but is there better solution?

Comment: can you try this >>> Container(
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: [
       //add your buttons here
    ],
  ),
);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the second row in an [`Expanded` widget](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rnZaagadyo), in this way the buttons portion will take the whole remaining space after the text.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 8.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
            child: Text("Input", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: this.getButtons(),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Then you should also wrap the buttons in `Expanded` widgets, removing the fixed width from the `SizedBox`:

```
  List<Widget> getButtons() {
    List<Widget> list = [];
    sourceNames.asMap().forEach((index, source) {
      list.add(
        Expanded(
          child: SourceButton(
            onPressCallback: () => {
              Fluttertoast.showToast(msg:"press down")
            },
            title: source,
          ),
        ),
      );
      list.add(SizedBox(width: 8));
    });
    return list;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MediaQuery` to get the device width and then keep the gap between buttons relative of device width.

Here is how you can get the device width and height.

```
double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
```

Comment: yes, I know. I can calculate button width use such as: width = (screen_width -   other_widget_width - total_gap)/button_number. but this is very common requirement in layout, have there a widget to support this ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Horizontal ListView is what you need. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6C5qvdUEfNc

Or you can use Expended widget contains 2 sized box on the left, right of Button. Check out Expended widget https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rnZaagadyo